# Change Label Row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, label

So I have an excel data like:

```
+---+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|   |   A    |    B     |    C     |    D     |    E     |    F    |
+---+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 1 | Name   | 266      |          |          |          |         |
| 2 | A      | B        | C        | D        | E        | F       |
| 3 | 0.1744 | 0.648935 | 0.947621 | 0.121012 | 0.929895 | 0.03959 |
+---+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

My main labels are on row 2. but I need to delete the first row. I am using the following Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file = 'Data.xlsx'

c1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
```

How do I make the 2nd row as my main label row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `skiprows` parameter to skip the top row, also you can read more about the parameters you can use with `read_excel` on the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)